# call a static method in User Control from js or ajax

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to call a static method in User Control from js or ajax.
It is possible to do this if the code method lies directly in WebForm but it is not possible to do it if we put the code method in UserControl and then put this UserControl in a WebForm.

### Code Behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat= ResponseFormat.Json)]  
    public static string GetNameFromCodeBehind (string name)
    {
        return "Hello from Code-Behind, " + name ;
    }
```

### AJAX Code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyUserControl.ascx/GetNameFromCodeBehind",
            data: JSON.stringify({ name: "Anton" }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e.statusText)
            }
        });
```

Ajax Error: 
Not Found

Comment: You cannot directly call a User Control.  If you move the Method into your parent page, then you can just call ```url: "MyPage.aspx/GetNameFromCodeBehind```

Comment: Why are you using WebMethod anyways? If you intend to call server side code from JavaScript, add a Web API controller and config.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I am developing a UserControls for SharePoint , So , I have to make through this way or using webservices ...
Actually , It is a bit not preferable with WebServices in the projects we develop ...

Answer (score 0):

If GetNameFromCodeBehind is inside MyUserControl.ascx, then it will be able to find a URL. Moreover, you have written the name of static method as callFromCodeBehind. So, you need to write the URL sccordingly

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
actually, the method name was just a write-failure .
I need the button to be triggered through a js.
Have the page reloaded with a new link parameters will cause the other elements in the User Control to loose their View-state, which is off course not the case if I raise an click event on code-behind...